# Plotting pairs of bins in a histogram for comparison with seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have a Dataframe which consists of some ML models with 2 columns for train & test accuracies respectively

```
evaluations_df
Out[13]: 
                    Model  train_accuracy  test_accuracy
0     Logistic Regression      100.000000      86.956522
1           Decision Tree       99.065421      84.782609
2           Random Forest       92.523364      82.608696
3            Ada Boosting      100.000000      89.130435
4       Gradient Boosting      100.000000      84.782609
5       Nearest Neighbors       88.785047      82.608696
6  Support Vector Machine       93.457944      82.608696
7             Naive Bayes       99.065421      89.130435
```

And I want to plot in similar to to this:

[image]

Where the `x` value is the number of models where it's ticks will be replaced by the model names, and the `y` value will be a pair of each accuracy metric.

I tried something like:

```
sns.histplot(data=evaluations_df, x=range(len(evaluations_df)), y=['train_accuracy', 'test_accuracy'],
                 color=['r', 'b'],
                 shrink=0.8,
                 multiple='dodge')
```

But it raises the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of list vectors must match length of `data` when both are used, but `data` has length 8 and the vector passed to `y` has length 2.
```

I don't seem to be able to unpack the `y` values as a pair of bins with that list.

Comment: To call `sns.histplot` directly, you need to convert the dataframe to [long form](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using seaborn and using just pandas you can do this:

```
evaluations_df.plot.bar(x='Model', y=['train_accuracy', 'test_accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thank you, it did what I wanted as intended, but still is there anyway to do it with seaborn? its presentation always looks better.

Comment: You can call `sns.set()` at the start to get a seaborn style.

Comment: @JohanC Just what I needed!